# How to correctly build an array

Tags: php

I'm having an issue getting this array into a format that I can use. There is additional data that is not showing up in my foreach loop. Can someone please look at the way I've built the array and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

There will be more than one dept and more than one location. The location is dependent on how many locations the department has.

```
   foreach...
    $arr[$db['name']] =
      array($db['date'] =>
        array($db['dept'] => (Need other departments to show)
          array($db['location'] => $db) (Need more locations for above dept.)
        )
      );
```

---

Gives me:

```
Array
(
  [training] => Array
  (
    [08-24-2011] => Array
    (
      [dept1] => Array <----------There is more than one department that should show
      (
        [dept1 Other] => Array <--There is more than one location that should show
        (
          [start_time] => 03:00
          [end_time] => 19:00
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

---

This is what I'm after. I just need to know how to order it so that my array produces this putput;

```
Array
(
  [training] => Array
  (
    [08-24-2011] => Array
    (
      [dept1] => Array
      (
        [dept1 Other] => Array
        (
          [start_time] => 03:00
          [end_time] => 19:00
        )
        [dept2 Other] => Array
        (
          [start_time] => 03:00
          [end_time] => 19:00
        )
      )
      [dept2] => Array
      (
        [dept1 Other] => Array
        (
          [start_time] => 03:00
          [end_time] => 19:00
        )
        [dept2 Other] => Array
        (
          [start_time] => 03:00
          [end_time] => 19:00
        )
        [dept3 Other] => Array
        (
          [start_time] => 03:00
          [end_time] => 19:00
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing something somewhat nonstandard. Could you show us an example of the array you would like to be getting?

Comment: @octern, What I'm doing is simply reordering my array from the database. I want to simply change the fields around

Comment: Your given input information is unclear. Why don't you try `var_dump` ?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain where the complication is coming from?  Building an array is just straight forward manipulation of another structure or scalar.  I don't see what's causing the confusion.  (Not meant in a mean way, but perhaps you should review arrays?  Unless there's something I'm missing that's complicating this.)

Comment: @Corbin, No offense taken. :)  Arrays have always been difficult for me especially when they are multidimensional. What I'm trying to accomplish here is to put the data in some sort of order that I can use. For example, in the array that's returned form the database, I have 17 rows of data. I would like a single array instead of 17, ordered by the name then the date and then to loop any other data for the departments and locations. I hope that makes sense

Comment: As Shivan said then, it would help to know your current structure and your desired structure in a clearer format.

Comment: @Corbin, I'm going to post the array in the format that I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the var_dump of the non-looped obj or array?

There are several possibilities. Here's a stab at a two of them:

1. The data that you've looped is not sufficiently workable with your foreach loop. I assume this is what's going on:

   ```
   $arr = array();
   foreach( $dbObj as $db )
   {
     //your loop goes here
     //
   }
   ```

You need to dump $dbObj in this case. Is it a 2D array like you're treating it? Perhaps it's really 3D and you aren't looping enough...

1. You are only pulling one item from your db with your query. Check that...

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I was pulling an associative array. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help! Things like this can be tricky until you've done it many times. :) Let me know if you get tripped up at any further point in the array build.